# Custom buttons in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

EDIT

Hi,
I have a project where I want to make a mobile web app with Jquery mobile. 
The problem I have is that when I am making a button with a custom button icon, I always get the plus icon. My custom icon is a PNG8 icon

This is what I do in my CSS

```
.ui-icon-myapp-phone { 
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(images/phoneIcon.png);
}
```

And I call it like this in my html.

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="ui-icon-myapp-phone">Contacteer klant via telefoon</a>
```

greetz

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What problem are you facing?  You do have a bug in your code. Change the \ to a / in the CSS file path.

Comment: I tried but it kept the same. I edited also my question.

Comment: It's still wrong. You should edit the CSS so you're using the / so that others don't focus on the typo and instead focus on solving whatever problem you're having.

Comment: You're question also doesn't make much sense. I encourage you to edit the heck out of this thing and describe exactly what a) doesn't work, and b) what the expected result is. Showing more code will help too as jQuery ui has a lot of dependencies. For instance, where is the HTML element with class="ui-icon-myapp-phone"? You're showing us CSS for something for which there is no HTML listed on your question.

Comment: I edited my question again. Hopefully its better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to overwrite some more CSS.

I'm doing it like this (using my own iconsprite). Feel free to patch it to your needs:

```
/* lo-res */
.ui-icon, .ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background: #666 /*{global-icon-color}*/;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
    /* your sprite URL or single icon URL */
    background-image: url(../images/icons/custom-icons-18-white.png) /*{global-icon-set}*/;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    }

/* hi-res */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
   only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
   only screen and (min-resolution: 240dpi) {

   .ui-your-icon-1, .ui-your-icon-2,... {
            background-image: url(../images/icons/custom-icons-36-white.png);
            /* IE-handle hack, serve lo-res */
            #background-image: url(../images/icons/custom-icons-18-white.png);
            /* your lo-res icon size dimenstions! One icon 36x18px, 50 icons 1800x18... */
            -moz-background-size: 1800px 18px;
            -o-background-size: 1800px 18px;
            -webkit-background-size: 1800px 18px;
            background-size: 1800px 18px;
            }
   }

   /* your individual icon background position */
  .ui-your-icon-1   {background-position:       0px -50%;}
  .ui-your-icon-2   {background-position:     -36px -50%;}
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I see what you are doing wrong:

Don't put the whole icon class in your data-icon handler!

**WRONG**

```
<a href="index.html" data-icon="ui-icon-myapp-phone">...</a>
```

This makes your data-icon into *ui-icon-ui-icon-myapp-phone*

**CORRECT**

```
<a href="index.html"data-icon="myapp-phone">...n</a>
```

To change the background color of the icon:

```
/* all icons */ 
.ui-icon {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  }
/* one icon only */
.ui-icon-myapp-phone {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

So your CSS should work if you correct the data-icon attribute in your HTML

Comment: Ok, but i don't want the icon in the grey circle. Is this also possible?